# How to convert a string array to an int array to access data inside int array?

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I have string similar to this

```
string text = "3;4;5;6;7;;3;4;5;6;7;;3;4;5;6;7;;3;4;5;6;7;;3;4;5;6;7;;";
```

I want to convert the above string into an int array like

```
[[3,4,5,6,7],[3,4,5,6,7], [3,4,5,6,7], [3,4,5,6,7], [3,4,5,6,7]]
```

I want to do this so that I can access each number because I want to do some maths like (3+4)/2 and (5+6)/2 for each set of array.

Until now I am using a simple split method:

```
string[] columns = text.Split(';');
```

and printing it by using:

```
foreach (var item in columns)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item}");            
}
```

But this has not worked and I am getting one number after another each indicating separate item. 
I want `[3,4,5,6,7]` as one item and 5 items inside this particular item and in integer form.
Can you help me with how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
var columns = text.Split(new[] { ";;" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);            
foreach (var column in columns)
{
     var numbers = column.Split(';').Select(y => int.Parse(y));
}
```

If you want empty entries, you have to Change the StringSplitOptions to `StringSplitOptions.None`

Comment: important to note that you added the StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries property (at the split function) .... maybe he wants to be able to create empty arrays for inputs like "1;2;;;;3;4" that should result in [[1,2],[],[3,4]]

Comment: No, I dont want to create empty array, infact I added two semicolons in the string(;;) to make it easier to divide the string in equal parts.

Answer (score 2):

```
var output = text.Split(";;", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => s.Split(";").Select(i => int.Parse(i)));
```

Split first on the `;;`.

Then for each group, split again on `;`.

Then parse each to int.

---

**Update as per comment**

I assume that empty entries need to be ignored, but if not, just remove the `StringSplitOptions`:

```
var output = text.Split(";;")
    .Select(s => s.Split(";").Select(i => int.Parse(i)));
```

Or if you need to be compatible with .NET Framework:

```
var output = text.Split(new [] { ";;" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => s.Split(';').Select(i => int.Parse(i)));
```

Or to include empty entries:

```
var output = text.Split(new [] { ";;" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(s => s.Split(';').Select(i => int.Parse(i)));
```

Comment: This won't work, because there is no string.Split(string) Method. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Same as for @SteveZ answer, important to note that you added the StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries property (at the split function) .... maybe he wants to be able to create empty arrays for inputs like "1;2;;;;3;4" that should result in [[1,2],[],[3,4]]

Comment: @SteveZ There is in .NET Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Split_System_String_System_StringSplitOptions_

Comment: I am using foreach loop to display items of outputs but getting this instead:  System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.String,System.Int32]

Comment: @VedantGonnade Your question stated that you wanted integers; if your simply writing to the console then `int.Parse` is an unnecessary step. Regardless, to write to the console you would do `foreach (var item in output) { Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", item)); }`

Comment: @VedantGonnade Your better using the [debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019) to check the state of your code. Writing to the console will often require a conversion of some sort.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I undertsand. I was using foreach loop just to see what has happened. I used string.join() and got output 3,4,5,6,7
3,4,5,6,7
3,4,5,6,7
3,4,5,6,7
3,4,5,6,7
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]].  But then I tried accesing each integer by output[1] but thats not happening

Comment: var output = text.Split(new[] { ";;" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Split(';').Select(i => int.Parse(i)).ToArray()); I just added .ToArray() at the end and now i can access the integers. but when I access item[0] output is 1 column and 5 rows of 3 but I wanted item[0] to be [3,4,5,6,7] and I tried using item[0][0] then error comes that : Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'

Comment: @VedantGonnade You need the `ToArray` at both levels to access by index: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3nEg5g